# Change in precision for numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, precision

I have been working on Mie scattering for particles.  The theory behind it is unimportant here, but the calculation does involve recurrence to estimate the Riccati-Bessel parts.  I initially did this via a "brute-force" method that stepped through various particle sizes, and the corresponding Bessel function recursions.  This took long (but worked), so I tried optimizing by using arrays.  Surprisingly, the array method did not even come close to the correct output.  The only thing I can think of is the arrays are not as precise as the more simple point-by-point method (that doesn't make sense, but it is all I can think of).

The difference can be seen in the plot created by the code posted below.  Can anyone say for sure whether this is an aggregated round-off error, or is there something else to consider?  I see no error in my code, though that does not mean an error isn't there!

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# BRUTE FORCE (STEP-BY-STEP) METHOD
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# user-defined parameters
N1 = complex(4 / 3, 1E-8)   # refractive index of particle
Nair = complex(1, 0)        # refractive index of air
wl = 0.500                  # wavelength of light (microns)
i = complex(0, 1)           # complex number (root of -1)
m = N1 / Nair               # ratio of refractive indices
r = [0.250]                 # particle radius (microns)
alpha = 2 * np.pi * r[0] / wl  # size parameter
max_iterations = 20         # maximum number of iterations
y = alpha * m

# define initial recurrence value for zeta
zeta_minus1 = np.cos(alpha) - i * np.sin(alpha)

A = np.zeros((max_iterations, 1), dtype=complex)
zeta = np.zeros((max_iterations, 1), dtype=complex)
an = np.zeros((max_iterations, 1), dtype=complex)
bn = np.zeros((max_iterations, 1), dtype=complex)

# calculate Qext, Qsca, A and zeta by recurrence
A[0] = np.cos(y) / np.sin(y)
zeta[0] = np.sin(alpha) + i * np.cos(alpha)

# calculate initial an and bn
n = 0
an_upper = (A[n] / m + n / alpha) * zeta[n].real - zeta_minus1.real
an_lower = (A[n] / m + n / alpha) * zeta[n] - zeta_minus1
an[n] = an_upper / an_lower

bn_upper = (A[n] * m + n / alpha) * zeta[n].real - zeta_minus1.real
bn_lower = (A[n] * m + n / alpha) * zeta[n] - zeta_minus1
bn[n] = bn_upper / bn_lower

for n in np.arange(1, max_iterations):
    A[n] = (-n / y) + (n / y - A[n - 1])**-1
    zeta[n] = (2 * n - 1) / alpha

    if n == 1:
        zeta[n] = zeta[n] * zeta[n - 1] - zeta_minus1
    else:
        zeta[n] = zeta[n] * zeta[n - 1] - zeta[n - 2]

    # calculate an and bn
    an_upper = (A[n] / m + n / alpha) * zeta[n].real - zeta[n - 1].real
    an_lower = (A[n] / m + n / alpha) * zeta[n] - zeta[n - 1]
    an[n] = an_upper / an_lower

    bn_upper = (A[n] * m + n / alpha) * zeta[n].real - zeta[n - 1].real
    bn_lower = (A[n] * m + n / alpha) * zeta[n] - zeta[n - 1]
    bn[n] = bn_upper / bn_lower

an_bruteforce = an.real.copy()
bn_bruteforce = bn.real.copy()
```

Array/matric method

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ARRAY/MATRIX METHOD
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# user-defined parameters
N1 = complex(4 / 3, 1E-8)   # refractive index of particle
Nair = complex(1, 0)        # refractive index of air
wl = 0.500                  # wavelength of light (microns)
i = complex(0, 1)           # complex number (root of -1)
m = N1 / Nair               # ratio of refractive indices
r = np.array([0.250])       # particle radius (microns)
alpha = 2 * np.pi * r / wl  # size parameter
max_iterations = 20         # maximum number of iterations
y = alpha * m


# pre-allocate arrays
A = np.zeros((alpha.shape[0], max_iterations), dtype=np.complex)
zeta = np.zeros((alpha.shape[0], max_iterations), dtype=np.complex)
an = np.zeros((alpha.shape[0], max_iterations), dtype=np.complex)
bn = np.zeros((alpha.shape[0], max_iterations), dtype=np.complex)

# define initial values for Riccati-Bessel functions
zeta_minus1 = np.cos(alpha) - i * np.sin(alpha)
n = 1
A[:, 0] = np.cos(y) / np.sin(y)
A[:, n] = (-n / y) + (n / y - A[:, n - 1])**-1

zeta[:, 0] = np.sin(alpha) + i * np.cos(alpha)
zeta[:, n] = ((2 * n - 1) / alpha) * zeta[:, n - 1] - zeta_minus1

# define initial values for an and bn matrices since the next "for" loop starts
# iterating on 2
an_upper = (A[:, 0] / m) * zeta[:, 0].real - zeta_minus1.real
an_lower = (A[:, 0] / m) * zeta[:, 0] - zeta_minus1

bn_upper = (A[:, 0] * m) * zeta[:, 0].real - zeta_minus1.real
bn_lower = (A[:, 0] * m) * zeta[:, 0] - zeta_minus1

an[:, 0] = an_upper / an_lower
bn[:, 0] = bn_upper / bn_lower


# now for n=1
an_upper = (A[:, 1] / m) * zeta[:, 1].real - zeta[:, 0].real
an_lower = (A[:, 1] / m) * zeta[:, 1] - zeta[:, 0]

bn_upper = (A[:, 1] * m) * zeta[:, 1].real - zeta[:, 0].real
bn_lower = (A[:, 1] * m) * zeta[:, 1] - zeta[:, 0]

an[:, 1] = an_upper / an_lower
bn[:, 1] = bn_upper / bn_lower


# calculate zeta, A, an, and bn via recurrence
for n in range(2, max_iterations):
    zeta[:, n] = ((2 * n - 1) / alpha) * (zeta[:, n - 1] - zeta[:, n - 2])
    A[:, n] = (-n / y) + (n / y - A[:, n - 1])**(-1)

    an_upper = (A[:, n] / m) * zeta[:, n].real - zeta[:, n - 1].real
    an_lower = (A[:, n] / m) * zeta[:, n] - zeta[:, n - 1]

    bn_upper = (A[:, n] * m) * zeta[:, n].real - zeta[:, n - 1].real
    bn_lower = (A[:, n] * m) * zeta[:, n] - zeta[:, n - 1]

    an[:, n] = an_upper / an_lower
    bn[:, n] = bn_upper / bn_lower


an_array = an.real.copy()
bn_array = bn.real.copy()
```

plotting

```
pl.close('all')
fig = pl.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = np.arange(20)[np.newaxis, :]
ax0.plot(x[0], an_bruteforce[:, 0] - an_array[0], 'k')
ax0.plot(x[0], bn_bruteforce[:, 0] - bn_array[0], 'r')

ax0.set_ylabel('Brute - Array', fontsize=10)
ax0.set_xlabel('Iteration', fontsize=10)
ax0.legend(('a$_n$', 'b$_n$'), fontsize=10, fancybox=True)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add an image of the plot too? Unrelated, your `i` can be spelt `1j` in python. It scares me that you have `i` under the heading "user defined parameters"!

Comment: It would be much easiler if you made the two halfs of your code as similar as possible. By this I mean: In one of you versions you `define initial values for Riccati-Bessel functions` before you `pre-allocate arrays`, and in the other version you do it in the reverse order with no particular reason. It's much easier for us to help you if you make our job easier ;)

Comment: And by the way, you are using `numpy arrays` in both your methods. What do you mean by "I tried optimizing by using arrays"?

Comment: @Eric, sorry, I didn't mean to scare you!  A plot has been added.

Comment: @TP You are right, and I apologize for the lack of congruity between methods.  Again, you are right that I am using arrays in both examples.  In the first example I calculate element by element, while I operate on entire rows/columns in the second example (i.e. to make things go faster).

Comment: I think your best bet is to come up with a [MCVE] that isolates the change in the way you do your calculation and, hopefully, the numeric instability you observe. Otherwise you're sort of hoping someone to either be familiar with your algo or spend the time to work through both of your implementations. You're probably in a better position to do that initial work.

Comment: In the second case it looks like `alpha` is a 1 element array, so that `A` is (1,n)` in shape, where as in the first you initialize it to `(n,1)`.  Other than that what's the difference?

Comment: @hpaulj Right, I've been beating my head on this for a few days now.  The point being, there should be no difference between the two methods other than the second takes advantage of the opportunity arrays offer to operate on entire rows/columns instead of element by element.

Comment: In the first case, `A[n]` is actually `A[n,:]`, a whole 'row'; in the 2nd it operates on a whole 'column`'.  Something else is different.

Comment: I would suggest that you separate the initialisation of your algorithm that is the same in both cases. And then create a function for each of the methods only containing the part of the algorithm you are doing differently. This way we know what to expect going in and out of those two functions.

Comment: There's a difference in how you handle the first 2 iterations.  It has nothing to do with the overall array dimensions.